# How to concatenate data into the same cell based from an array or in different cells that are already stored?

Tags: excel, vba

How do i put multiple values from different cells (eg: values that lies below header x rel and y rel previously obtained by my program) and put them in the same cell which lies the same row as device d?(not manually select in excel or selectively using coding). What my current code does is to locate the x and y values of reliability fails then stored them in array(not sure is it correct or not) but after that how to concatenate them in the same cell shown in "After"?

```
Public Sub FindAndConvertforreliabilityfails()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastRow     As Long
Dim myRng       As Range
Dim mycell      As Range
Dim MyColl      As Collection
Dim myIterator  As Variant
Set MyColl = New Collection
Dim xpos As integr, ypos As Integer

MyColl.Add "x rel"
MyColl.Add "y rel"
Dim LastCol As Integer
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To LastCol
For j = 1 To lastRow

For Each myIterator In MyColl
Do While Sheets(1).Cells(1, j).Value <> ""
If Sheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = myIterator Then
xpos(j) = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Else
ypos(j) = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If
Loop
Next
Next

' how to continue from here for the concatenate portion?

End Sub
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**

[image]

Currently

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will give you the expected output.

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim output As Variant
Dim outputrow As Integer
output = ""
outputrow = 0
For i = 2 To 5 'change 5 to lastrow of F&G Column.
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = 0 Then
        output = output & "(" & Cells(i, "F").Value & "," & Cells(i, "G").Value & "),"
    Else
        Cells(i, "E") = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
        output = "(" & Cells(i, "F").Value & "," & Cells(i, "G").Value & "),"
    End If
Next i
Cells(i, "E") = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: hi dude, do i try this together with my code or just yours?

Comment: ah thanks alot but right now the code isnt at the same row as deviced(at row5,col5) but  is at device e(row 6,col 5), so how do i fix that?

Comment: and lets say if the data vary like for eg the last row number i <>  4, can i use i = 2 to lastrow where lastrow=  sheets(1) .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  ?

Comment: It would be better to use last row of F and G column. lastrow=Columns("F:G").Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

Comment: And about your first question:Can we relate the position of output with lastrow of F column or is it dependent on some other column?

Comment: eh the position of output is based when there is a number that lies below  reliability fails header. For eg in this case there is a data = 3 that lies below reliability fail at column B row 5 so i want the output to lie at the same row...

Comment: i was thinking of using new collection stuff to do that but still unsure of the syntax..

Comment: reliability fails lie means where value of B column is converting from zero to non-zero?

Comment: But Collection is not required here. you can achieve the expected output in simple way.

Comment: sorry just now my explanation is unclear..as long as the value is zero under reliabilitty fail header, just ignore them, where as if there is a value, put the output under the same row as where there is a value?

Comment: so by right the row that is same as devicee at column E should have an output also..

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. My bad i didnt update my own "After" picture, so the output should be something like that shown above..

Comment: i just posted a picture of the current output just in case if you misunderstand...thanks alot btw..